# Migrating from Flex 4/4.5 to 4.5.1 for mobiles

Tags: flash, apache-flex, adobe, flash-builder, flex4.5

I am trying to migrate from flex code written in flex 4/4.5 using mx to be compatible with flex 4.5.1 using only spark.

The problem is that I can't find a few mx component in spark so any help will be appricated:

mx:tree
mx:text
alert.show()

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Spark equivalent of MX `Tree` control in Flex SDK. But anyway this control is too "heavy" to use it in mobile apps considering resources (performance). I think you should rethink your GUI and introduce some lightweight version of it.

`mx:Text` can be replaced with [`s:Label`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7fde.html) or [`s:RichText`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7fca.html) depending on need you formatting or not. You can see features comparison table [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b167739a25a5e12695211e42-7fff.html).

Finally, `Alert`. There is no Spark equivalent of MX `Alert` out of the box. Spark architecture has [`SkinnablePopUpContainer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS67cd75b2532ad652-1abb110512d5bda966d-8000.html) which can be used to create your own alert with possibility to customize it for your application. For example to use iPad-like pop ups.

Update. There is some [third party Spark `Tree`](http://kachurovskiy.com/2010/spark-tree/) implemented.

Comment: If you are looking to do a mobile app with this, then stay away from the RichText component and use ['s:Label'](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html) or ['s:StyleableTextField'](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/StyleableTextField.html) as the RichText component is not optimized for mobile. You can find good info about what is good and what isn't for mobile [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSf3db6597adcd110e19124fcb12ab3a1c319-8000.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any replacement for the MX tree. If you rally don't want to use it, you can check out this page :

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Spark_Tree-17788.html

For the Text component, use either of the following depending on your needs (I suggest s:Label, it's much faster) :

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7fff.html

There's no Spark alert, but if you really can't use the mx control, use the PopUpManager to display any flex component as a popup and set the modal option to true. However, the TileWindow component is a really base popup component that you can extend if you need to. More infos on TileWindow :

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS6c678f7b363d5da52e8f1ca1124a0430dcf-8000.html

Here's an example of using the PopUpManager :

```
        _legalPopup = new LegalMentionPopup();
        _legalPopup.title = "Legal Mention"

        PopUpManager.addPopUp(_legalPopup, FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as DisplayObject, true);
        PopUpManager.centerPopUp(_legalPopup);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the sample. I would have given you also accepted answer but there can be only 1 and @Constantiner answered before.